# Which default .config to start from when compiling kernel?

Tags: debian, kernel, compiling, make, configure

I was reading the [Debian handbook here](https://debian-handbook.info/browse/stable/sect.kernel-compilation.html#sect.config-kernel), and  it says:

> "When recompiling a more recent version of the kernel ... the
>   configuration will most likely be kept as close as possible to that
>   proposed by Debian. In this case, and rather than reconfiguring
>   everything from scratch, it is sufficient to copy the
>   /boot/config-version file (the version is that of the kernel currently
>   used, which can be found with the uname -r command) into a .config
>   file in the directory containing the kernel sources."

Four paragraphs later, it also says:

> "it is always a good idea to start from a reasonable default
>   configuration. The kernel provides such configurations in
>   arch/arch/configs/*_defconfig and you can put your selected
>   configuration in place with a command like make x86_64_defconfig (in
>   the case of a 64-bit PC)"

What is the difference? Which is the best to use? Should I grab the .config from /boot/config-(currentversion) or just run "make x86_64_defconfig" to create the .config?

I plan on changing the options manually, but I'd like to start from the existing kernel's configuration as originally offered by the distro.

Answer (score 0):

I also compile my own kernel (on Debian), and I ended up just running `make gconfig` with no `.config` in the directory (so it uses whatever the defaults are for Debian I think) the first time. I then tweaked it (deselected a bunch of irrelevant modules and so on) and now I have a much leaner kernel (haven't stopped tweaking it!).